# Codelens not working with Git submodules in VS 2013/2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, codelens

It seems to me as the Microsoft Git Provider is not working flawlessly. I noticed that I do not get any information on author and changes in Codelens in **some** of my solution's projects. These projects happen to be **git submodules**, so I suspect the issue to be centered around that.

Is there some configuration I need to make, in order to get the Microsoft Git Provider to work? Will Codelens work better with another provider (if there even is another usable Git provider for VS 2013/2015)?

Comment: "We plan to support Git submodules but we don't have support for it yet.  Hopefully we'll get to working on it in the next few months." says Microsoft, two years ago. :-(  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2014/07/02/vstfs-2013-3-update-3-rc/